# Massless particle in FRW metric

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, lagrangian-formalism

How is it possible to define the energy for a massless particle in a Freedman-Robertson-Walker metric if the Lagrangian is not invariant under time-translation? 
I have postulated the simplest Lagrangian for a massless particle (a Lagrange multiplier times the constraint) and it is obviously not time-invariant.
Not only: if I work since at the beginning using the proper time as a evolution parameter, the dynamics in the Lagrange parameter and the spatial components is physically inconsistent, giving meaningless results like a scale factor equal to the Lagrange multiplier.
Is there something wrong in my assumption for the Lagrangian?

Comment: The energy of photons is not invariant, and their energy is not conserved in General Relativity, and specifically in the FRW metric. As the universe expands the energy of a photon for an observer in the comoving reference frame decreases due to the cosmological redshift. The math is consistent with the physics. The photon just follows a null geodesic in the metric.

Comment: Why do you think that invariance under time translation is needed for the *definition* of energy? You can look at the generator of time translation (which becomes a Noether charge if the physics are time translation invariant) regardless of whether it is conserved or not. Whether that's useful is a different question.

Answer (score 1):

The energy of photons is not invariant, and their energy is not conserved in General Relativity, and specifically in the FRW metric. The energy is hf, and f depends on the dynamics of the temporal part of the spacetime, so as time dilates or contracts the frequency changes. A red or blue shift.

As the universe expands the energy of a photon for an observer in the comoving reference frame decreases due to the cosmological redshift. The math is consistent with the physics. The photon just follows a null geodesic in the metric.